# Jquert Ul Li search using boostrap panel not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the jquery sim tree plugin to show tree categories. [Sim Tree](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Checkable-Hierarchical-Tree.html)

I have added a search bar to the filter tree data. What I want is to expand the inner ul li elements.

[image]

[image]

Working Fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/dnetk0s9/

**The issue is when I search the text second it does not work. (the panel is not expanding).**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Checkable-Hierarchical-Tree/dist/simTree.css">
      <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <title>sim-tree: Checkable Hierarchical Tree Demo</title>
      <style>
         body { min-height: 100vh; background-color: #fafafa;}
         .container { margin: 150px auto; max-width: 640px; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      </script>
      <div class="container">
         <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" value="" id="demo_2" placeholder="" autofocus style="margin-top:10px;"/>
         <br/><br/>
         <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                     <a data-toggle="collapse" class="ul-laspe" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                     One
                     </a>
                  </h4>
               </div>
               <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="tree">
                        <div id="tree"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" class="ul-laspe" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
                  Two
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="tree">
                     <div id="tree2"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Checkable-Hierarchical-Tree/dist/simTree.js"></script>
      <script>
         var list = [{
         "id": '1',
         "pid": '',
         "name": "hi foo bar",
         },
         {
         "id": '11',
         "pid": '1', // parent ID
         "name": "bye tar"
         },
         {
         "id": '12',
         "pid": '1',
         "name": "welcome rat"
         },{
         "id": '13',
         "pid": '1',
         "name": "why this"
         },{
         "id": '14',
         "pid": '1',
         "name": "match this"
         },
         {
         "id": '2',
         "pid": '',
         "name": "raw input"
         },
         {
         "id": '21',
         "pid": '2',
         "name": ""
         }
         
         ];
         
         var list2 = [{
         "id": '1',
         "pid": '',
         "name": "X JavaScript",
         },
         {
         "id": '11',
         "pid": '1', // parent ID
         "name": "X Angular"
         },
         {
         "id": '12',
         "pid": '1',
         "name": "X React"
         },{
         "id": '13',
         "pid": '1',
         "name": "X Vuejs"
         },{
         "id": '14',
         "pid": '1',
         "name": "XY jQueryScript.Net"
         },
         {
         "id": '2',
         "pid": '',
         "name": "X HTML5"
         },
         {
         "id": '21',
         "pid": '2',
         "name": ""
         }
         
         ];
         var tree = simTree({
             el: '#tree',
             data: list,
             check: true,
             linkParent: true,
             //check: true,
             onClick: function (item) {
                 console.log(item)
             },
             onChange: function (item) {
                 console.log(item)
             }
         });
         var tree = simTree({
             el: '#tree2',
             data: list2,
             check: true,
             linkParent: true,
             //check: true,
             onClick: function (item) {
                 console.log(item)
             },
             onChange: function (item) {
                 console.log(item)
             }
         });
         
         
         $('.sim-tree li').each(function(){
             $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
         });
         
        $('#demo_2').on('change', function() {
            //$('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
            var searchVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            if (searchVal != '') {
                $('.sim-tree li').each(function() {

                    var currentLiText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                    showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchVal) !== -1;

                    if (showCurrentLi) {

                        $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
                        $(this).children("i").click();
                        $(this).find("ul").addClass("show"); //show ul inside li

                    } else {

                       $(this).closest('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
                       $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
                        $(this).children("i").addClass("layui-icon-r").removeClass("layui-icon-d")
                        $(this).find("ul").removeClass("show");

                    }

                });
            } else {
               // $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
                $(".sim-tree").find("ul").removeClass("show") //find any ul has show class remove it
                $(".sim-tree").children("li").children("i").addClass("layui-icon-r").removeClass("layui-icon-d") //find li children `i` change icon
            }
        });
         
         
      </script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi try `currentLiText.includes(searchVal)` instead of `currentLiText.indexOf(searchVal) !== -1` .

Comment: @Swati issue is not in search, panel is not expanding second time

Comment: how are they expanding on what circumstanes?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, if data found in any panel it will expand.

Comment: @c.grey are you seeing that behaviour [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0otuqpzh/) as well ?

Comment: @Swati, yes, use onchange instead of onkeyup

Comment: I am not sure why that's not working :/ in keyup its working fine .